# how to upload 'django-rest-api server', and 'crawling.py'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, aws-lambda, web-crawler

[image: django architect]

Hi, guys.
i have a problem.

i made an android application written by kotlin.
this app communicates to 'django-restapi server' to get some data.
'django-restapi server' gets data from 'crawling.py' file(using selenium,headless chrome).

app : show data to people
django-restapi server : get data from crawling.py, and saving data on database
crawling.py(with chromedriver) : crawling data from website, and sending data to server

so, what i want to know is, i don't know how to upload them.
i want to use aws.
what i'm thinking now is, upload 'django-restapi server' and 'crawling.py' to aws lambda seperately.
 then, i will run 2 lambda.
but i think it's bad architecture.

can you advice me better answer?

Comment: and crawling.py runs once in ten minutes!

Comment: How about using EC2?

Comment: i think ec2 is also good alternative. i think it will runs on lambda , ec2 both. but i want to know better choice with reason